# pdf to txt tvs or vcf in R, ubuntu

Tags: r, pdf

I have the next link

[1] https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByCmoyvCype7ODBMQjFTSlNtTzQ

This is a pdf file. The author of a paper gave the list of mutation in this format.
I need to annotate the mutation of this file. 
I need a txt or TVS or VCF file to be reading by annovar.

Can you help me to convert this using R or other software in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

In principle this is a job for [`tabulizer`](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer) but I couldn't get it to work in this instance; I suspect the single table over so many pages confused it.

You can read it in to R as text with the `pdftools` package easily enough

```
library(pdftools)
txt <- pdf_text("selection.pdf")
```

Now `txt` is an R list, with each element of the list a character string for a single page in the original document.  You might be able to do something fancy with regular expressions to convert this to more meaningful data.

However, it makes more sense to ask the original author for their data in an appropriate format.  Publishing a 561 page PDF of tabular data is just nuts.